# New Install of Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Fails Ambiguously

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation

After purchasing a single license copy of VS 2015 Pro from the online Microsoft store, we downloaded the web installer executable vs_professional.exe.

When we start this .exe, whether running as administrator or not, the following happens in order:
: the VS splash bar appears (contains the VS logo and the words Visual Studio)
: the splash bar disappears
: the VS splash bar re-appears
: the monitor goes completely black and although the system is running, there is no viable interface

The monitor remains black forever (well, at least over an hour).  The system must be force-restarted by holding down the power button.

After the screen goes black, if we attempt to remote desktop to the installation system from elsewhere on the network, the remote login hangs on the "welcome" screen.

The target system is a Dell Precision M6500 32-bit running Windows 7 SP1.  There is over 19Gb of free space on the root drive.  The video interface is a Quadro FX 3800M.

Any insights on how to diagnose or workaround this issue are greatly appreciated.